# R.java not automatically generated

Tags: android, installation

I'm trying to upload an app called SMS from my computer to my phone.  When I check for devices connected my phone shows up as connected.  I have tried other apps and they do upload but there are a few that do now like this one call SMS.  The following is what I do and see on the command prompt when I try to upload it:

```
C:\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb install "C:\Users\Computer Engineer\Desktop\SM
S.apk
1248 KB/s (16618 bytes in 0.013s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/SMS.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

Why does this happen and what do I need to do in order to be able to upload it to my phone?

Comment: What does this have to do with R.java not being generated? I think this question is better suited for android.stackexchange.com as it has no programming elements to it (only copying a program from PC to Phone).

Comment: irrelevant title and question, were these supposed to be two separate questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you compiled your application to an SDK newer than the SDK of
your device. ([API Levels explained](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html))
In order to successfully upload to device, you need to decrease your minSDK version in your android manifest file. Keep in mind that some features may require the higher SDK version, and might not work properly, or not work at all. ([Android compatibility explained](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html))

Comment: I apologize for the question title and the actual question content differences.  I'm new to this forum.

Comment: And actually, I do have the "R.java" file problem also.  When I compile my code it's supposed to generate a "R.java" file in the gen directory, but that is not happening.  I have tried cleaning Project-->Clean, but that does not help either.  With the compile error I get "R cannot resolve to a variable" error at the following code portion:

Comment: // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.
  setContentView(R.layout.voice_recognition);
  
  // Get display items for later interaction
 Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
 mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
 mSupportedLanguageView = (Spinner) findViewById          (R.id.supported_languages);

Comment: no, it does not.  When I try to run the simulation I get a box with a "Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application" error.

Comment: that's why you don't have R generated.

Comment: Why?  Where do you suggest I have the errors.  The code I found it at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html

Comment: I just copy and paste it to my project.

Answer (score 0):

Your minSDK version in your android manifest is higher than the version of android running on your phone.